# How does the OS X port of .NET avoid the non-native GUI appearance of Java apps?

Tags: java, .net, macos, user-interface

Java desktop applications using the Swing toolkit are notorious for [non-native look and feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056360/java-swing-guis-on-mac-os-x) compared to native OS X apps using Cocoa or even Carbon.  To a lesser extent this problem affects Java apps on Windows, and all other cross-platform GUI libraries, from Qt to Tk.

Does the newly announced .NET port to OS X take any new steps to avoid this situation and get closer to the goal of ["write once, run anywhere"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere) with native look and feel?  Or will OS X .NET apps have a non-native "Windows-y" feeling to them?

Comment: No no... The ported .NET doesn't include Winforms nor Wcf, so no graphical interface. Look at the image from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/12/04/introducing-net-core.aspx Only ASP.Net for Linux and OsX . [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-12-34/5488.Pic2.png) picture

Comment: @xanatos: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/

Comment: @SLaks *Does the newly announced .NET port to OS X* He isn't speaking of Mono, he is speaking of .NET core

Comment: Can the GUI toolkits listed (on the Mono page SLaks linked to) be used on top of the new .NET Core port?

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller: Probably not.  But why bother? Mono works fine.

Comment: @SLaks "Mono works fine" and "GUI" are difficult to put in the same sentence. But this is my uninformed opinion.... Winforms hasn't ever been a main "target" for the Mono project, Gtk# is nearly abandoned (it is supporting Gnome 2.* and only on 32 bits if I remember correctly), MonoMac I don't know.

Comment: @xanatos: If the frameworks don't work fine, running them on a different runtime won't help.  (I've never actually used Mono)

Answer (score 1):

.NET Core 5 for OS X does not support desktop application development.

If you refer to Mono, Xamarin.Mac provides bindings to native OS X APIs such as Cocoa, so your app works just like any other Cocoa apps.

**Update: I also made [a blog post on .NET cross platform UI framework](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea).**